# remove lines perl with multiple search patterns

Tags: bash, perl, solaris

I'm trying to find a way to use perl to remove lines that contain:

```
errors:
mirror
raid*
pond
```

I've managed to find:

```
perl -pi -e "s,errors:,,"
```

Is there a way to specify all patterns that I'm looking for in one command?

Comment: Simple in grep, `grep -Ev "errors:|mirror|raid*|pond" file`

Comment: It's Solaris unfortunately `-E` option does not exist but you are right, why over complicate. `egrep` worked like a charm.

Comment: ^^ try with `grep -v -e pattern1 -e pattern2` then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention Perl you can use:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /errors:|mirror|raid\*|pond/'
```

Alternative you can use sed or grep:

```
sed '/errors:\|mirror\|raid\*\|pond/d'
```

Or grep with re`-v`erse:

```
grep -v 'errors:\|mirror\|raid\*\|pond'
```

You can add the `-i`nplace flag to both sed and Perl

Answer (score 1):

Using `egrep` as `Solaris` didn't support the `-E, --extended-regexp` option

```
egrep -Ev "errors:|mirror|raid*|pond" file
```

Another way with `awk`

```
awk '!/errors:|mirror|raid*|pond/' file
```

Thanks to [`anishsane`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793796/anishsane) suggestion in the comments, using `grep` with multiple expressions,

```
grep -v -e "errors:" -e "mirror" -e "raid*" -e "pond" file
```

Comment: The Perl snippet will print lines not starting with `errors:`, ... OP is asking for contains. Also note that `*` is a meta character and should be escaped to be treated literally.

Comment: @andlrc: taken down the `perl` solution. Tried ways to fix it, what could be the optimal way with my logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way:

```
open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;

while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    if ($line =~ m/errors:|mirror|raid\*|pond/)
    {
        next;
    }
    print $line;
}
close $fh;
```